# Problem with IIS for creating file on Servers Folder

Tags: asp.net, iis, blazor

I have an AspNet App (Blazor) running on IIS server.
I would like to create a txt file on the server, but it doesn't work.
I changed the AppPool identity to a domain user accound and the directories in E: have full permissions for this account.

It works in VisualStudio IIS Express, but not in IIS.
Anyone here who can help me? A permission problem`?

C# Code for creating txt file:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"E:\Publish\Export\Test.txt", "Hello World");
```

Comment: What kind of drive is E? Mapped drive? Also what kind of Blazor? WebAssembly or Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save to a specific path, use [MapPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.mappath?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_Page_MapPath_System_String_) (or [Server.MapPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524632(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)) to get the physical path corresponding to the application. Because by default the web server (IIS or local development server) will save to its working directory.

Also you need to make sure the account running IIS has read/write permissions to the directory you need to write to. If you're looking for user accounts, go to "Advanced Settings" under Application Pools and check what's set for "Identity".